# Confusion in proof of Two representations are equivalent if $\text{dim}(\text{Hom}^G(V,W))=1$.

Tags: representation-theory

I am confused about one specific part of this proof, which I highlight in bold. I have put in a clipping of the proof from the notes I am working through, and then explained what I understand beneath that.

Note that the author uses $\Im \phi$ instead of $\text{Im}\phi$.

---

[image]

---

So we have shown that $\ker(\phi)$ and $\text{Im}(\phi)$ are invariant subspaces. Since the the representations are irreducible we have $\ker(\phi)=0$ or $V$ and $\text{Im}(\phi)=0$ or $V$.

I understand that if $\phi$ is not the zero map then it is an isomorphism.
So if the representations are not isomorphic the only maps between them are the zero map.

> **I do not understand why this gives that $\text{dim}(\text{Hom}^G(V,W))=1$ when the representations are isomorphic?**

I think this is because of the following but I am unsure about each of these points

1. $\text{Hom}^G(V,W))$ is the set of intertwiners
2. in a on dimensional space two elements only differ by scalars
3. Schur's lemma gives that $\phi^{-1}\circ \psi = \lambda I$ but why does this give that $\phi$ and $\psi$ differ by scalars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes, and this is an equivalence (that's what's important since you want to prove one-dimensionality)
3. Compose with $\phi$ to get $\psi = \lambda \phi$

Comment: Perphas this should be a separate question, but is the converse of this true? I am trying to show that $\text{dim}(\text{Hom}^G(V,W))=1$ implies that the representations are isomorphic but can't see how this follows

Comment: It is true if they are irreducible : any element in this hom-space is either zero or an isomorphism, so if there's one that isn't $0$, it must be an isomorphism