# $\text{dim}(\text{Hom}^G(V,W))=1$ implies that isomorphism of representations

Tags: representation-theory

Let $(\pi, V)$ and $(\rho, W)$ be two irreducible representations.
I am trying to prove that $\text{dim}(\text{Hom}^G(V,W))=1$ if and only if $(\pi, V)$ and $(\rho, W)$ are isomorphic.

I have shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3430133/confusion-in-proof-of-two-representations-are-equivalent-if-textdim-textho) that when $(\pi, V)$ and $(\rho, W)$ are isomorphic it follows that $\text{dim}(\text{Hom}^G(V,W))=1$ but I do not see how to go about doing the other direction.

I feel that if $\text{dim}(\text{Hom}^G(V,W))=1$ then $(\text{Hom}^G(V,W))$ consists of $1\times 1$ matrices? Then they would have to be invertible? But this does not seem correct.

Comment: Is $G$ a finite group? Reps over $\Bbb{C}$?

Comment: This is precisely Schur's lemma, isn't it?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen representations over $\mathbb{C}$, $G$ is not finite but $V$ and $W$ are.

Comment: @Gabriel I don't see how to use Schur's lemma here, you very well could be correct I just do not see how to apply it

Comment: In that case Schur's lemma does apply. Using a **fixed** isomorphism lets us identify $Hom^G(V,W)$ with $Hom^G(V,V)$ **as vector spaces**. If the latter has dimension $>1$, then there are non-scalar endomorphisms. As the dimensions are finite, an eigenspace must be a non-trivial submodule, arriving at a contradiction.

Comment: Oh, may be that is the other direction? If there is a non-zero homomorphism $V\to W$, then its kernel and image must be $0$ and $W$ respectively, implying that it is an isomorphism. Again, straight out of a proof of Schur's lemma.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you this makes sense. If you combine your two comments into an answer I will accept it to close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a closer look in Schur's Lemma. In its most common form, it says that:

> Let $(\pi,V)$ and $(\rho,W)$ be two irreductible representations (over $\mathbb{C}$) of $G$. Then:
>
> 1. If $(\pi,V)$ and $(\rho,W)$ are not isomorphic, then there are no nontrivial equivariant maps between them.
> 2. If $V=W$ and $f$ is an equivariant map between them, then $f=\lambda\:\mathbb{id}$, for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$.

For the first point, it says that $\hom^G(V,W)$ consists of only the trivial map. In other words, $\hom^G(V,W)$ is the trivial vector space and hence it is $0$-dimensional.

For the second point, we have to do just a little more work. The theorem says that $\hom^G(V,V)$ consists of all the maps on the form $\lambda\:\text{id}$. Thus $\{\text{id}\}$ is a basis for $\hom^G(V,V)$ and it is $1$-dimensional. But what about $\hom^G(V,W)$, when $(\pi,V)$ and $(\rho,W)$ are isomorphic? Well, if $F:V\to W$ is an equivariant isomorphism, then
\begin{align*}
\hom^G(V,V) &\to \hom^G(V,W)\\
 h &\mapsto F\circ h
\end{align*}
is an isomorphism between $\hom^G(V,V)$ and $\hom^G(V,W)$. We conclude that $\hom^G(V,W)$ is also $1$-dimensional.

This shows that Schur's Lemma is precisely the statement below.

> Let $(\pi,V)$ and $(\rho,W)$ be two irreductible representations (over $\mathbb{C}$) of $G$. Then, $\hom^G(V,W)$ is $1$-dimensional if and only if $(\pi,V)$ and $(\rho,W)$ are isomorphic. Else, if they are not isomorphic, $\hom^G(V,W)$ is $0$-dimensional.

Comment: These seems to be lacking some details.

Comment: @Emily, you did exactly the same thing as I did. Your argument is precisely the proof of Schur's lemma, which I've cited. If there's something which is not yet clear, I'll be glad to help. (However, I don't think it is ok to write an answer saying the same thing as I did.)

Comment: My answer was based off Jyrki's comments. I would accept Jyrki's comment as the answer if that was possible, (and will accept their answer if they post one). Your answer does not have many details. In the comments you said "This is precisely Schur's lemma, isn't it?" which I told you I did not understand. And this answer did not expand on that comment much. As I did not understand your answer, I certainly did not intend to just write what you wrote. If you flesh out your answer I will accept it, but I will give time for Jyrki to post an answer since I found their comments most helpful.

Comment: @Emily, I think it is better now. Tell me if there's something else I can clarify for you.

Comment: Thank you, this a good answer. The statement I had seen of Schur's lemma did not include your (1) part of the statement. It was just (2) and a partial converse of (2).

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based of Jyrki's comments.

Suppose that $\text{dim}(\text{Hom}^G(V,W))=1$. Then there is a non zero map $\phi\in \text{Hom}^G(V,W)$.

It can be shown that if $\phi$ is non zero, then it must be an isomorphism. 
To do this show that $\ker(\phi)$ and $\text{Im}(\phi)$ are invariant subspaces (This is shown in the linked question). Next use that the representations are irreducible. Since $\phi$ is nonzero $\text{Im}(\phi)=W$. This gives that $\ker(\phi)\neq V$ and hence $\phi$ is an isomorphism and we are done.